# Magento 2 multi store and multi domain - Notice: Undefined index: store;

Tags: magento2, multistore, multidomain

I am trying to set up my local mac to have 2 stores in 1 magento instance

The main domain (www.mydomain.dev) is working as expected however the french domain (www.mydomain-fr.dev) is not loading and giving me

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: store; in /Users/myuser/Sites/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/ReaderList.php on line 50
```

Please could anyone advise? My vhost.conf looks like the following if it helps

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName mydomain.dev
            ServerAlias *.mydomain.dev
            Include "/Users/myuser/Sites/ssl/ssl-shared-cert.inc"
            CustomLog "/Users/myuser/Sites/logs/dev-access_log" combinedmassvhost
            ErrorLog "/Users/myuser/Sites/logs/dev-error_log"

            VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/myuser/Sites/mydomain
        </VirtualHost>

     <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName mydomain-fr.dev
            ServerAlias *.mydomain-fr.dev
            Include "/Users/myuser/Sites/ssl/ssl-shared-cert.inc"
            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE frenchstore_view;
            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            CustomLog "/Users/myuser/Sites/logs/dev-access_log" combinedmassvhost
            ErrorLog "/Users/myuser/Sites/logs/dev-error_log"

            VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/myuser/Sites/mydomain
        </VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**

If I update the index.php in root from:

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
```

To

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'default'; 
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

Then the french domain works. Am I meant to be editing the index.php?

The store hierarchy is the following

```
Main website     UK Store        UK Store View
Main website     French Store    French Store View
```

Comment: Could you share the hierarchy in terms of websites, stores and views?

Comment: I have updated the question with in it, hope this helps

Comment: I could give you an answer... but it would include certain guesswork, could you also add the code (available when you press on the web site, store and store view links available in admin at Stores > All stores) and which is the default? 

As of now, my guess is that you override whatever you set in htaccess / vhost.conf in index.php; your .dev domain doesn't work - you get the french no matter what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OP post apache vhost config is incorrect

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE frenchstore_view;
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
```

Parameters should be in double-quotes and no semicolons.

Correct one:

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "frenchstore_view"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"
```